# sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: Http Error: 404 Not Found

Tags: google-app-engine

When I initialize gae sdk v1.8.1 with dev_appserver.py via command line I get

`sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: Http Error: 404 Not Found.`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: are you trying to run it while offline?

Comment: No. I make sure I am connected

Comment: you can pass --skip_sdk_update_check when you run it, which should let you develop locally. Probably still worth trying to figure out what the problem is though, if it isn't temporary.

Comment: Also, try using the latest version. The current version is 1.8.3 and can be obtained from https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version, the problem disappeared.